# Webscraping with Python, BeautifulSoup findAll() doesnt find all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and am currently trying to build a webscraper to learn the language. I want save all listings from https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/studentenprogramm/notebooks, which is all Notebooks that fall under the category of Student offers from this site.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/studentenprogramm/notebooks'

uClient = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"mouseover clearfix"})
```

I am trying things out in the console as well, but when I check the len of containers, this is the output I get:

```
>>> len(containers)
1
```

Which can't be right, since the listings per page are set to 50.
I have tried searching with different parameters, but I always just seem to find one item, then the search stops.

I am a little lost right now and can't quite figure out how to fix this problem. Any help?

Greetings :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is embarassing.

Just after I posted it (in my defense after multiple searches and endless trying around), I realized that html classes can't contain spaces and that mouseover clearfix is actually 2 classes.
This works:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"mouseover"})
```

Comment: You can also do what you originally wanted by using the `soup.select` method with a CSS selector: `page_soup.select('div.mouseover.clearfix')`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That's definitely something that will be useful.